# Is it Possible to use HQL in Hibernate @Subselect annotation?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, subquery, hql

I am getting result if I use SQL in @Subselect. Is it possible use HQL in this annotation?

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select * from Foo_table")
public class FooView
```

Like

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select a from FooEntity a")
public class FooView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is not possible, because according to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class

> There is no difference between a view and a base table for a Hibernate mapping. This is transparent at the database level, although some DBMS do not support views properly, especially with updates. Sometimes you want to use a view, but you cannot create one in the database (i.e. with a legacy schema). In this case, you can map an immutable and read-only entity to a given SQL subselect expression using @org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect

and it will be directly executed as query statement for DB, without HQL layer and transformation from HQL to pure SQL... but you can play with it and test

Comment: It would be nice if we can use it.